# FLUTTER- I want to post and fetch datas from database

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter project and I want to fetch datas which I post to database. I can post successfully (I can see them in my database) but I cannot fetch data. I want your help... please help me... the codes, explanation and the problem below here.

the code:

```
class GetId {
  String id;

  GetId({this.id});

  factory GetId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GetId(
      id: json["id"],
    );
  }
}

Future<GetId> sendData() async {
  _DenemeState controls = new _DenemeState();

  final response = await http.post(
    "https://www.ekrts.com.tr/bloom/get.php",
    body: {
      "id": "${controls.idController.text.toString()}"
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    return GetId.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {

    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class _DenemeState extends State<Deneme> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController surnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController idController = TextEditingController();
  Future<GetId> futureGetId;

  Container _getValues() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            nameController.text.toString(),
          ),
          Text(
            'textfield değeri ' + idController.text.toString(),
          ),
          Text(
            "Response: ",
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureGetId = sendData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Register"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "ad",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'ad'),
                ),
                Text(
                  "soyad",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: surnameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'soyad'),
                ),
                Text(
                  "id",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: idController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'id'),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Register"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _getValues();
                      sendData();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                _getValues(),
                FutureBuilder<GetId>(
                  future: futureGetId,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data.id);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }

                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation:

GetId class: This class contains the data from network request

Future sendData(): This class connects my database and post the data to database, I can see them.

Container _getValues(): I created to see my data from the database on screen.

And my problem, I cannot see the data on emulator screen but I can post and see on database. I hope, I could explain my problem... please help me...

Comment: What are the database you are using?

Comment: I created mysql database

Comment: Then what language are you using for the backend to create the API

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      id= user.uid;
    });
```

i hope you are asking for something like this. you can load the user id to `id` variable from this.

Comment: i''m sorry. i misunderstood